# RSpec: testing cancan with home-spun authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cancan

This is a simple question, it's just that I'm still wrapping my head around RSpec's syntax & methodology...so I'm a bit confused. Please bear with me..I'm wondering how to approach testing controllers (and requests, etc.) when **Cancan** is involved and users can have different levels of authorization.

I've read that one advantage to Cancan is that it keeps all Auth in one model...great! but it seems to have confused testing for me...so I'm looking for advice.

Background: I'm using a bitmask to hold the authorization level for the user (a la [Railscast #189](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association)). So the integer column `roles_mask` will hold all the auth for a user. Not sure this matters but now you know.

I'd like to have some tests as a guest user that should fail if guest tries to create a Post. But then in same `posts_controller_spec` I'd like to test that an `admin` and `moderator` can *create* the same post. Just not sure how best to set this up.

So, should I have a factory for a guest user, one for an admin, etc... Moving `@user.roles_mask = 1` to a describe block before specs I want for an "admin" user doesn't work. No method errors. But, if I assign the roles_mask in the Factory it does work?!? So how can I test for varying levels of roles_mask? (nil, 0, 1, 2, 4, etc?)

```
describe PostsController do

  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory(:user)
    session[:user_id] = @user.id 
    @attr = Factory.attributes_for(:post)
  end

  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all posts as @posts" do
      post = @user.posts.create(@attr)
      get :index
      assigns(:posts).should eq([post])
    end
  end

  ...

  describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Post" do
        expect {
          post :create, :post => @attr
        }.to change(Post, :count).by(1)
      end
  ...

  end

# posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :login_required, :except => [:index, :show]
  load_and_authorize_resource
  ...
end
```

Factory:

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.sequence(:email)       { |n| "foo#{n}@dummycorp.com" } 
  user.password               "foobar"
  user.password_confirmation  { |u| u.password }
  user.firstname              "foo"
  user.roles_mask   1                       # < --- remove & tests fail
                                            # < --- how to manipulate dynamically in tests
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused (as I was) by the fact that the controller is protecting access to resources - but it's still the ability class that determines whether the controller's actions can be carried out on a particular resource.  Whether you access the resources through the PostsController or some other controller, should really make no difference - you still don't want guests making posts.  If you really want to be certain that load_and_authorize_resource is being called in the PostsController you could set up a single functional test for that (guest create post should fail) - then the ability tests should confirm the detail.

```
 require "cancan/matchers"
describe Ability do
  before(:each) do
  end
  [Contact, Question, Provider, Organisation].each do |model|
    it "should allow any user to read a #{model.to_s} details but not delete them" do
      user= Factory(:user)
      ability = Ability.new(user)
      ability.should be_able_to(:show, model.new)
      ability.should_not be_able_to(:delete, Factory(model.to_s.underscore.to_sym))
    end
  end

  [Contact, Organisation].each do |model|
    it "should allow any admin user to delete a #{model.to_s} " do
      user= Factory(:admin)
      ability = Ability.new(user)
      ability.should be_able_to(:delete,  Factory.build(model.to_s.underscore.to_sym))
    end
  end
```

etc

In my case I have admin users and normal users with different abilities - I just created one of each in turn, and called the relevant methods on the models I wanted to restrict access to. I didn't actually test the controller much at all because load_and_authorize_resource is called in my case in the application_controller and so a single test makes sure it applies throughout the app

Comment: This is helpful, thanks! Go enjoy your dinner, but when you get back maybe you could look at this again. What you provide is helpful for testing the `Ability` class itself...at least that's the way it looks to me. But my problem remains: now that I've 'wrapped' a controller with Cancan so that authorization is restricted...how do I go about testing the controller so Cancan doesn't break everything? Should I just test everything as an :admin (which gets things passing)? Or, set up different describe blocks for each role? If so, how?